# How to setDescription of the name of a element in facet?

Tags: vaadin

I need help about how to add description on facet, here I will put my code so you could see what I am thinking :

```
List<Facet> facetsExecutor = findFacets("executorFaceting", "caseFileUserApps.activeUsers.executor", fullTextQuery, queryBuilder, includeZeroCounts);
addMoreFacets(najdeniFaceti, facetsExecutor, rb.getString("com..........executor"));
for(int i=0;i<facetsExecutor.size();i++){
    String name=facetsExecutor.get(i).getValue();
    setDescription(name); //The method setDescription(name) is undefined for the type HibernateIndexSearch
}
```

Could someone help me, because I need the look when my mouse is over the name of the element in the facet to show a field with specified text(name of the element in the facet)???

Comment: What is your definition of a `Facet`?

Comment: Facet is restriction... something like quick search

Comment: Please improve your question by adding all the relevant code.  This post should help you do that : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve